# Force.com - custom report type

Tags: force.com, custom-report-type

I made a custom report type . I included a few objects and related them using object relationships which was correctly displayed in the set (Venn) diagram . However , the fields of these objects are not available for editing in the edit layout detail of 'Fields available for reports " section. The fields are visible but am unable to make changes to them . Please help.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the issue you are facing, as it is unclear to me where it's going wrong?

Comment: Thank u very much for your help . Actually the fields were not visible at all but i tried it again today and they are visible now must have been some error in the page .

Answer (score 4):

This is somewhat tricky and is explained well [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005196&language=en_US).

> Go to Setup -> Create: Report Types -> Click on the Report Type's Label -> Click
>   "Edit Layout" within the "Fields Available for Reports" box on the
>   right, you'll see the "Field Layout Properties" section. 
> You can drag
>   and drop desired fields to this layout. If a field you wish to include
>   is not visible under one of the selected objects, you may be able to
>   add it via lookup. 
>   To do this Select the respective object from the
>   "View" drop down field on the right side of the page.  Click on the
>   "Add fields related via lookup »" link directly below the "View" drop
>   down field.  Select the appropriate link and subsequent fields. Repeat
>   this process as needed per object.